# EF code-first can there be multiple entities in DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

We are using EF 6.x with [RefactorThis.GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff); so that a related entity-tree is saved/updated using EF.

We have added RowVersion for each table to capture the concurrency as we are using UoW + Repository pattern with disconnected contexts.

The solution provided at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904) page has the following code-snippet:

{

var entry = ex.Entries.Single();

}

My question is - is it possible to get more than one entry in the "ex.Entries" ?
Will all of them be having Concurrency issue?

Also, additional question - is it possible that RowVersion of "DB" value be smaller than "Original" values?

Comment: Great question, actually. I wonder why there is no answer yet after almost 7 years...

Answer (score 0):

No, you still cannot get more then one entry at a time. Unless they fix it, github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1002

But you still can catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException as many times as it will be raised, deciding every time how to resolve conflict. Let's get the code sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) and slightly change it:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

using var context = new PersonContext();

// Fetch a person from database and change phone number
var person1 = context.People.Single(p => p.Id == 1);
person1.PhoneNumber = "555-555-5556";
var person2 = context.People.Single(p => p.Id == 2);
person2.PhoneNumber = "555-555-5557";

// Change the person's name in the database to simulate a concurrency conflict
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    "UPDATE dbo.People SET FirstName = 'Jane' WHERE PersonId = 1;" +
    "UPDATE dbo.People SET FirstName = 'John' WHERE PersonId = 2;");

var saved = false;
while (!saved)
{
    try
    {
        // Attempt to save changes to the database
        context.SaveChanges();
        saved = true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Person)
            {
                var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                {
                    var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                    var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                    // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                    // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                }

                // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                    + entry.Metadata.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```